# Coded UI Test Builder won't record actions within the Visual Studio window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I have an MVC web application that I wanted to try out coded ui tests on and it sounded simple enough. I would say that starting up the web app would be a pretty important part of the test but the Coded UI Test Builder will not record any actions that I take within Visual Studio such as hitting F5 or clicking on the run arrow.

How am I supposed to test a web app if I can't even start it within the test. I can't really expect everybody using these tests to start up the app and have it open in a window before they actually run the tests, it just seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

Coded UI is about testing the UI of your application, it is not about testing that you can use Visual Studio. (I imagine that there is some way of using Coded UI in Visual Studio to test the UI of Visual Studio, but that sounds complicated.) You use Coded UI to, firstly, create a test of your application. So start the Coded UI record and generate tool. Next start you application from the Windows **Start** button, or the desktop. You should see Coded UI recording the steps to start the application. Then record any other steps needed for the test. When the recording of the test is completed you should eb able to run the test.

To learn about testing with Coded UI, I suggest you first try creating some simple tests using the Windows Calculator or Windows Notepad. There are several examples and turorials, including videos, on the web. See for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEOkMaacx2Q

Comment: Except I'm testing an MVC web application with it, not a desktop app which would just be a simple .exe to run. There's a fairly complex deployment process that is all scripted up, and it's not trivial to load it up outside the Visual Studio process. I want it to be a completely automated part of a test suite, not something where the user of the tests has to do something besides hitting 'Run All Tests'.
I'm not entirely sure that you've understood what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am sure I have not understood what you are trying to achieve, and I suspect no one else has either. Perhaps you could explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: As you have a script to start the application, you should be able to call it from the **.testsettings** file which has a section for startup and shutdown scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this because I am looking at the same thing. I am coming from webdriver, and want to try Coded Ui on an MVC app.

My issue is that the coded ui simply needs to start a browser and navigate to a page. That's fine in an environment where the application has been deployed, but at development time it is difficult because you are using IIS Express that starts and stops as you debug the app. In the past I have found ways to automatically start and stop IIS Express and publish my web app during a debug build of my test project. It worked for web driver, I see no reason it will not for coded UI. Take a look at my blog post on the subject. I am about to look at it my self, so may well post another article if I get it working.

http://www.radicalgeek.co.uk/Post/12/starting-up-iis-express-for-a-specflow-and-selenium-webdriver-test-run

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a batch file that runs whatever you need first then the coded UI. You can automate this with a windows task or an automation script.